# Is there a name for this type of sculpture?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

On a recent outing I discovered a number of these.

Essentially, you look through the hole in the middle and you are facing a landmark, city, specific location, etc.

Whilst this one is clearly modern, I am sure this type of thing existed historically.

Do they have a name?  The place I saw them doesn't have them named anywhere I could see.

Comment: These aren't natural formations?

Comment: @Mitch Haha! They may well be!

Comment: Cf. the late [Old Man of the Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Man_of_the_Mountain), a long but now destroyed New Hampshire tourist attraction.

Comment: @Robusto - Yeah, but look!  Mine has METAL!

Comment: This looks like some sort of "henge".

Comment: I'm confused... at first I thought you were talking about the Stonehenge-looking things on the left and right, but after reading the question, I thought you were referring to the metal object in the middle. You're right, they have had these before; I've seen some that looked like mounted red telescopes. If you're only referring to the object's functionality, I would call it a _stationary sight_.

Comment: I'd go with "neomegalithic", but I've just spent the past two days fixing genres in my music library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many years ago my friends and I used to pore over local maps looking for potential [ley lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_line). We'd select one for "on-site" investigation, then get out and walk along it - usually for several miles.

I was always struck by how often we were able to use footpaths, bridle paths, turnstiles, etc., and how often we encountered striking views across the landscape, and [geodetic monuments](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=define%20geodetic%20monument&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

> [geodetic monument](http://termwiki.com/EN%3ageodetic_monument) *- a stone or concrete pillar that marks a true place of trigonometric points*.

Here's a Wikipedia page on the [Peirce **Geodetic Monument**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_Geodetic_Monument). Such points won't *always* offer a clear view to a notable landmark. But they're always precisely positioned in relation to *something*, so very often this will be the case.

Comment: Why thank you, sir! I knew there was a name other than "trig points".

Answer (score 2):

"Geodetic monument" does *not* apply to the viewfinder shown in the photograph. Unlike the archaeological (i.e., old and the consequence of human activity) monuments in the photograph, a geodetic monument is simply for designating the precise location of specific latitude-longitude and/or elevation coordinates. Nothing of the kind is visible or implied in this illustration. Such monuments were commonly erected during the surveys establishing boundaries, for instance: large enough to remain in place and to bear the carved or affixed coordinates of that location, but certainly not the mammoth features shown here.

I recommend "viewfinder" for this means of focusing the visitor's gaze upon the distance feature. I've never seen one during my extensive travels in the U.S. and Canada. How nice to see this rather than the coin-operated telescope that is common here.